# WHILE loop not looping

Tags: linux, bash, shell, while-loop

I'm fairly new to Linux and shell scripting.

My problem is, that the script should read 2 tokens from a file called "list" - using these tokens, it creates a user and depending on the second token, a sub folder. It does this just fine - but only once. Only ONCE. Is there a problem with my WHILE loop?

Here is a few sample lines from "list":

```
egyes n
kettes y
harmas y
```

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo " " >> /root/userpass.txt
most=$(date)

while read user rr; do
    p1=${user:0:2}
    p2=${user:3:4}
    pass=$p1$RANDOM$p2
    echo $user - $pass --" LÉTREHOZVA: "$most >> /root/userpass.txt

    adduser $user > /dev/null
    echo $user:$pass | chpasswd > /dev/null

    uhome=/home/$user

    if [ $rr=="y" ]; then
            mkdir $uhome/rockandroll
            chown $user $uhome/rockandroll
    fi

    mkdir $uhome/res-devres
    chown $user $uhome/res-devres

    ftpc=/etc/proftpd/proftpd.conf

    echo "#"$1 >> $ftpc
    echo "<Directory "$uhome"/res-devres/>" >> $ftpc
    echo '  <Limit CDUP XCUP STOR LIST CWD XCWD STOU>' >> $ftpc
    echo '          AllowAll' >> $ftpc
    echo '  </Limit>' >> $ftpc
    echo '  <Limit RETR DELE>' >> $ftpc
    echo '          DenyAll' >> $ftpc
    echo '  </Limit>' >> $ftpc
    echo '</Directory>' >> $ftpc
    echo " " >> $ftpc
    echo " "
done < list
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: something eating the stdin?

Comment: note: storing passwords as plain text is a bad idea...

Comment: it is for temporary use, just until I send them out. After that I delete the file, but that's not the point.

what do you mean "eating the stdin"?

Comment: any process that's reading from stdin will process the input of your loop. you can find it with simple elimination..

Comment: Yeah, probably that's the one - how can I stop it from accessing stdin after doing it's job?

Answer (score 2):

change from

```
if [ $rr=="y" ]; then
```

to

```
if [ $rr == "y" ]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, some command in your loop is reading from standard input. You can either figure out which command that is, and redirect its standard input from `/dev/null`:

```
bad_command < /dev/null
```

or simply use a different file descriptor for the while loop:

```
while read user rr <&3; do
    ...
done 3< list
```

Now the `read` command is not reading from standard input, but from file descriptor 3, which is unlikely to be in use by any command in the body of the loop.

---

As pointed out by BMW, you need to fix your `if` statement:

```
if [ "$rr" = "y" ]; then
```

The spaces around the equal sign are necessary, as `[` is a command, not part of the `if` syntax, and it requires 3 distinct arguments (`$rr`, `=`, and `"y"`); it will not parse the single string `$rr="y"` as a comparison. `=` is preferred with the `[` command, as generally `==` is not the POSIX equality comparison operator. However, `bash` does allow `==`, but also provides a superior command which does not require `$rr` to be quoted as required for safety with `[`:

```
if [[ $rr == y ]]; then    # == or = will work the same
```

---

You can save some typing in the last section of your loop by combining the `echo` statements into a single compound command and redirecting their combined output once:

```
{
    echo ...
    echo ...
    echo ...
} > "$ftpc"
```

Another option as pointed out by tripleee, requires only a single call to `cat`. It spawns an external process, but looks cleaner.

```
cat > "$ftpc" <<EOF
#$1
<Directory $uhome/res-devres/>
etc
EOF
```

You could also just `echo` and a single string with embedded newlines.

```
echo "#$1
<Directory $uhome/res-devres/>
etc
" > "$ftpc"
```

Comment: The `echo` pain would be alleviated by the use of a here document, too.